# Look for element in string and return element + following two characters

Tags: python, string

The following html appears as **a string** in my code. That is okay, what I need though is how to get:

"class="company-image company-34""

for each company-## there is also a price found in this tag further below in the HTML:

class="small-12 medium-4  cell text-right" data-after="kr./år">**1.813**

I tried following code:

```
for x in html:   
    if "company-image company" in x:
        print("Oh yes")
    else:
        print("Nahh")
```

but it doesn't really work. My thinking is I look for everytime "company-image company" is mentioned and get the whole string and the following numbers after, it is always two numbers ##. And whenever it is found I look for "data-after="kr./år"" and get the numbers following. Eventually this would end in a for loop, as there are multiple companies and prices.

```html
<app-offer-match _ngcontent-vdv-c20="" _nghost-vdv-c22="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="box">
        <!---->
        <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="line1">
            <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="company-image company-34"><img _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" src="/assets/images/companies/34.svg"></div>
            <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="button compare">Sammenlign </div>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="line2">
            <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="container-button">
                <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="button mini-accordion"></div>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="container-insurance-list">
                <!---->
                <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="indbo ng-star-inserted">
                    <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="grid-x container-product-overview">
                        <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="small-5  cell detail"><span _ngcontent-vdv-c22="">Indbo</span>
                            <!----><span _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="ng-star-inserted">Kongshaven 3</span>
                        </div>
                        <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="small-6  cell">
                            <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="grid-x price">
                                <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="small-12 medium-8  cell text-right" data-after="kr.">Selvrisiko 2.199</div>
                                <div _ngcontent-vdv-c22="" class="small-12 medium-4  cell text-right" data-after="kr./år">1.813 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</app-offer-match>
```

EDIT: Added desired output.
Desired output would be a pandas dataframe of:

```
Company                   Price
company-image company-34  1.813
```

EDIT 2:
It looks like an xml, that's because I formatted it like that for you guys. WHen I output it, it is of type STR, thank you.

Comment: A library like `beautifulsoup` can be helpful.

Comment: It is not really clear what the problem is from the question? Would you perhaps try crafting a [minimal example](/help/mcve) reproducing the issue?

Comment: Your code is xml, and for that you should be using something like lxml. If you can use that, I can post an answer. And you might as well post your exact desired output.

Comment: Added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
company = """[your string above]"""

import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

doc = lh.fromstring(company)

columns = ["Company", "Price"]
rows = []
targets = doc.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"company-image company")]')
for target in targets:
    row = []
    row.append(target.attrib['class'])
    price = target.xpath('../following-sibling::div//div[@data-after="kr./år"]')[0]
    row.append(price.text)
    rows.append(row)
rows
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
Company     Price
0   company-image company-34    1.813
```